# flash embedded into captivate communication: call advanced action?

Tags: flash, adobe-captivate

Currently using Captivate 7.. Ok, so you can reach into Captivate and grab variables using cpEIGetValue(x), and set vars using cpEISetValue(x), but can you call an advanced action that you have set up in Captivate? I cannot find any information on this.